# How to pass parameter to getJson request of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My getJson function returns expected json array only if I pass parameters statically. If I pass a variable containing values, it doesn't returns array.

```
$.getJSON('http:....UserAppData/SendCurrentPoints.php',{Route: "Sangli-Vishrambag-Miraj", Bus_Number: "DL 16 AS 1242", date: "2017-04-15", Time: "12:59"}, myCallBack);
```

The above code returns correct array but below code returns nothing. I checked the values that I am passing which are exactly same to that which I passed above. My PHP page on that url uses GET method.

```
        var arglist={
      Route:rt,
      Bus_Number:bus,
      date:"2017-04-15",
      Time:tm
    }
    $.getJSON('..../UserAppData/SendCurrentPoints.php', arglist, function(data){
//      localStorage.setItem("way",data.Points[0]);
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: it seems correct, can you try console.log(JSON.stringify(arglist)); just before: $.getJSON, this is just to verify the values are intact right before the call.

Comment: Thank you so much... This solved my problem. The problem was each value in arglist initiating with '\n', that's why it was not matching the database query.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Yes I agree.. I'll not repeat the same..